# Click a link that will navigate to a new page and open B5 modal on new page

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have a footer link that will redirect users back to the home page and should open an existing modal.

The only reference I was able to find is below, however it does not work.

Page with link:

```
$('.nav-link').on('click', function (e) {
  location.href = "index.html?showModal=1";
});
```

Target page with modal:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if(showModal == 1){
       $('#modal').modal('show');
  }
})
```

Comment: How did you implement this code? Where is it located? What happens?

Comment: The first code snippet lives on the secondary page and the second on the main index. Index console error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: showModal is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not properly [fetching the `GET` parameter](https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/).
You need to define `showModal` as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   let showModal = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('showModal')
   if(showModal == 1){
       $('#modal').modal('show');
  }
})
```

If it still fails perhaps you need to [get the BS Modal instance](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#getinstance), and call `show()` on that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   let showModal = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('showModal')
   if(showModal == 1){
       let myModal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById('modal'));
       myModal.show();
  }
})
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so very much

Comment: Did you have to do both steps or did the first one work?

Comment: The first step worked perfectly.